# Comma placement for speaker's name in publication

Tags: commas, names

I'm editing a flyer someone else wrote and I have the following sentence:

> Our storytelling series launches with featured speaker, Aloysius Firefly, professor of arts.

I think ought to be "... speaker Aloysius Firefly, professor of arts." What do you think?

Comment: You got it right. That's editing and you have that power. Also, is Professor of Arts a formal title in your land?

Comment: Ha, many thanks for the power!

Professor of Arts is a short hand I used for the example. The professor's real title wasn't relevant to my questioning outside of the grammatical context it provides. 

Thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: You probably want something like "our featured speaker" or "the" or "a" (depending on what comes before), rather than just "with featured speaker" unless it's something where it's OK to miss out articles and other unimportant words and you don't need to be fully grammatical.

Comment: 'featured speaker' is arguably not an appositive here as << Our storytelling series launches with featured speaker >> is not a shorter option (except in telegraphese). Ditto Professor of Arts. There isn't an equivalence between the three NPs. As 8356 says, no comma is inserted between NPs such as [fast bowler] and [Malcolm Marshall]. However, a comma **_is_** used between NPs such as [William] and [Bishop of Waterford].

Comment: **Professor of Arts Aloysius Firefly will launch our storytelling series as featured speaker**. Start with the person, not the event. I think your writer did not know their business. Look, Daddy, no comma needed.

Comment: Nothing wrong with << Our storytelling series will be launched by featured speaker Aloysius Firefly, Professor of Arts. >>

Comment: Note that @EdwinAshworth has capitalized the title, “Professor”, the lack of which is, IMHO, what **is** wrong with the original.

Comment: @Lambie Why? The person is, in my opinion, what matters, not his title, his spouse or whether his sexual activity has resulted in offspring. (In fact, what he has done — his claim to deserve a hearing — is even more important. And I would certainly include a comma.

Comment: @David The person who wrote that can't write. Sure, make it appositional with a comma but make the sentence start with the person, not the event. Storytelling series *launches* ain't great. It is just bad writing.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a comma before the name in constructions such as these:

Prosecutor John Smith, state's attorney of Cook County, said....

The play by Harold Pinter, a modernist storyteller....

The performance with soloist Chantel Juliet, piano, and Misha Viator, violin...

A series with featured speaker Studs Terkel, the Chicago writer and broadcaster...

Multiple sources and grammar guides, including AP and CMOS, endorse the no-comma before a name construction (unless the name forms a non-restrictive clause). For a discussion of names and comma/no comma rules, see [this article by Ben Yagoda in the New York Times](https://archive.nytimes.com/opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/05/21/the-most-comma-mistakes/#:%7E:text=The%20basic%20idea%20is%20that,don%27t%20use%20any%20commas).

Comment: I agree, but can you supply an endorsing reference, 83?

Comment: There are many, so I added a link to an NYT article by an English professor and author, which contains many examples and discusses the 'rules'